# django import csv in several related models

Tags: python, django, csv, import

For a web application of naturalistic data for the study of bats (http://www.dbchiro.org), I need to be able to propose a view allowing to import files from spreadsheets (csv, ods files , xls) into database. To import this data into a single table, no problem, several extensions exist (django-import-export or django-csvimport in particular). On the other hand, my need is more particular because my naturalistic data is distributed in several distinct tables (not counting the tables of dictionaries).

Here is the schematic diagram:

1. Model **Place** Place (a locality is a site with unique x / y
   coordinates as a building).
2. 1-n Model **Session** (one data = one date and one inventory method by locality)
3. 1-n Model **Sighting** (one data = one species per session)
4. 1-n Model **CountDetail** (one data = 1 detail for a species: eg number of males, number of females, etc.)

What I would like to get is the ability to import the data of a session with a single csv file that would populate the last two models: Observations (Sighting) and for each observation (each species observed), its detailed data (CountDetail).

Is there one or more simple solutions (I'm doing well but I'm not a great python expert either).

Otherwise, the solution that I imagined would be to load this csv data (in a specific model?) and for each import, to execute queries to populate models :

1. Import the source file ( CSV, ods, excel) by form.
2. Create and insert the data set in the parent table with the command "select distinct" on the fields corresponding to the observation model (species).
3. Then for each species of the session (for ...), creation and insertion of the data in the child table (CountDetail).

I am taking advice / examples / snippets :)

Thank you!

Fred.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    id_place = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    [...]

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Localité"
    unique_together = ['name', 'municipality', 'type']



class Session(models.Model):
    id_session = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact,models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, verbose_name=_("Type de contact"))
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Localité associée')
    date_start = models.DateField(
    verbose_name='Date de début', help_text=_('Format de date: <em>01/01/2017</em>.'))
    [...]
    timestamp_create = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    timestamp_update = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now=True, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False, related_name='session_creator')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False, related_name='session_modifier')

    def __str__(self):
    return "%s ∙ %s ∙ %s" % (
        self.place, datetime.date(self.date_start.year, self.date_start.month, self.date_start.day), self.contact)

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Session d'inventaire/observations"
    unique_together = ["place", "contact", "date_start"]

class Sighting(models.Model):
    id_sighting = models.AutoField(_('id unique'), primary_key=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(
    Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Session associée'))
    period = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Période d\'observation'))
    codesp = models.ForeignKey(
    Specie, on_delete=DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=_('Espèce ou groupe d\'espèce'))
    total_count = models.PositiveIntegerField('Nombre total', blank=True, null=True, help_text=_('Désactivé pour les données acoustiques et en main'))
    breed_colo = models.NullBooleanField(
    verbose_name='Colonie de reproduction')
    [...]
    timestamp_create = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    timestamp_update = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now=True, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False, related_name='sighting_creator')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False, related_name='sighting_modifier')

    def __str__(self):
    return "%s ∙ %s ∙ %s" % (self.session, self.codesp, self.total_count)

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Observation"
    verbose_name_plural = "Observations"
    unique_together = ["codesp", "session"]


class CountDetail(models.Model):
    id_countdetail = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sighting = models.ForeignKey(Sighting,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='countdetail_sighting')
    method = models.ForeignKey(Method, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name=_('Méthode'), blank=True,
                           null=True)
    sex = models.ForeignKey(Sex,models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name=_('Sexe'))
    age = models.ForeignKey(Age,models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True,null=True,verbose_name=_('Age estimé'))
    [...]
    timestamp_create = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    timestamp_update = models.DateTimeField(
    auto_now=True, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False, related_name='countdetail_creator')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False, related_name='countdetail_modifier')

    def __str__(self):
    return "%s ∙ %s ∙ %s ∙ %s" % (self.sighting.session.place.name, self.sex, self.age, self.count)

    class Meta:
    verbose_name = "4 ∙ Comptage détaillé"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use django-import-export.

in admin.py you can create class resources and add to admin.

admin.py

```
    from .models import Place,Session
    from import_export import resources,widgets
    from import_export.fields import Field
    from django.contrib import admin

    class SessionResource(resources.ModelResource):
        id_session = Field(column_name='field_id_sesion_excel',attribute='id_session')
        place = Field(column_name='place_field_excel', attribute='place', widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Contact))

        class Meta:
            model = Session
            skip_unchanged = True

        def before_import_row(self,row, **kwargs):
            value = row['place_field_excel']
            obj = Place.objects.create(id_place=value) #create object place
            row['place_field_excel'] = obj.id # update value to id ob new object

        def save_instance(self,instance, using_transactions=True, dry_run=False):
            try:
                instance.save() # inside try for ignore error on duplicate primary keys
            except:
                pass

    @admin.register(Session)
    class SessionAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
        resource_class = SessionResource
```

and you can import from csv,xls,etc.